# Object is 'null' during PageView animation, works when animation ends

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to create a blog like app using flutter. I have created a home page that displays some tiles, each tile representing a post, and clicking on the tiles would take you to the blog post.

I have created a preview tile widgets class that takes in image, text, title, and controller as parameters. These are then passed on to the post page through cupertino page route.

So everything kinda works as expected, when I click on the tiles, it takes me to the page I want to with the data, but when I'm scrolling through the tiles in the page view, if the tiles are clicked on mid scroll, I get an error

```
    'package:flutter/src/painting/image_resolution.dart': Failed assertion: 
    line 134 pos 15: 'assetName != null': is not true.
```

Here's what I have:

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  HomeScreenState createState() => HomeScreenState();
}

class HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen>{

  final PageController _controller = PageController(viewportFraction: 0.80, initialPage: 0);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    Widget horizontalList1 = GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.of(context).push(ArticlePageRoute());
      },
      child: FadeUp(
          child: Container(
              child: PageView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                controller:_controller,
                children: <Widget>[
                  PreviewTile(image:"lib/images/tile.jpg",title: "Title 1 - Lorem Ipsum", text: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.",controller: _controller),
                 ...
                ],
              ))),
    );

    Widget home = Container(
        child: MediaQuery.removePadding(
          context: context,
          child: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              header,
              horizontalList1,
            ],
          ),
        ));

    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      body: home,
    );
  }
}
class ArticlePageRoute extends CupertinoPageRoute {
  ArticlePageRoute() : super(builder: (BuildContext context) => ArticlePage());

  // OPTIONAL IF YOU WISH TO HAVE SOME EXTRA ANIMATION WHILE ROUTING
  @override
  Widget buildPage(BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation,
      Animation<double> secondaryAnimation) {
    return ArticlePage();

  }
}
```

```
class PreviewTile extends StatefulWidget {
  final String image;
  final String text;
  final String title;
  final PageController controller;

  PreviewTile(
      {@required this.image,
      @required this.title,
      @required this.text,
      @required this.controller});

  @override
  _PreviewTileState createState() => _PreviewTileState();
}

class _PreviewTileState extends State<PreviewTile> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget tile = GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.of(context).push(ArticlePageRoute(widget.title,widget.text,widget.image));
      },
      child: Container(

        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(

              child: ClipRRect(
                child: ParallaxImage(
                  controller: widget.controller,
                  image: AssetImage(widget.image),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Material(
                        child: Text(
                          widget.title,
                        )),
                    Material(
                      child: Text(
                        widget.text,
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                )),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
    return tile;
  }
}

class ArticlePageRoute extends CupertinoPageRoute {
  final String titleText;
  final String bodyText;
  final String imageURL;

  ArticlePageRoute(this.titleText, this.bodyText, this.imageURL) : super(builder: (BuildContext context) => ArticlePage(image:imageURL,title:titleText,body:bodyText));

  // OPTIONAL IF YOU WISH TO HAVE SOME EXTRA ANIMATION WHILE ROUTING
  @override
  Widget buildPage(BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation,
      Animation<double> secondaryAnimation) {
    return ArticlePage(image:imageURL,title:titleText,body:bodyText);
  }
}
```

```
class ArticlePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String image;
  final String title;
  final String body;

  ArticlePage({
    this.image,
    this.title,
    this.body});

  @override
  ArticlePageState createState() => ArticlePageState();
}

class ArticlePageState extends State<ArticlePage> {
  final ScrollController _controller = ScrollController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget header = GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.pop(context);
      },
      ...
          child: ParallaxImage(
              controller: _controller,
              image: AssetImage(widget.image),
             ...
              child: Container(
              ...
                child: Text(
                  widget.title,
                 ...
                ),
              )),
        ),
      ),
    );
   ...
    Widget home = Container(
        child: MediaQuery.removePadding(
          context: context,
          child: ListView(
            controller: _controller,
            children: <Widget>[header, body],
          ),
        ));
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      body: home,
    );
  }
}
```

I think the data is somehow detached during the animation but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: is all this code needed to fullfil [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? I doubt that. Please trim it down.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski sorry about that, I deleted as much as possible

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had a GestureDetector on top of my PageView Widget, I removed it and everything worked perfectly.

Comment: Any clue how to do this when you need the GestureDetecture? I've got the same problem, but I can't delete the GestureDetector.